# -[NSCFDictionary initWithObjects:forKeys:count:]: attempt to insert nil value at objects[0] (key: sourceRelationship)

Tags: core-data, crash, migration, persistent-storage

I am having a pretty bad night with this one. I have been running and testing my code on iOS 5.0 since I had to quickly update.. I had installation problems so 4.3 Simulator wasn't available to me until just recently. I (thought I had) worked out all of my lightweight Core Data migration issues. Tonight, I went to run the app in the 4.3 Simulator and on an iPad running 4.3. What I found was awful.

This error every time:

> 2011-10-27 07:01:44.045 AppName[924:10d03] *** Terminating app due to
>   uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '***
>   -[NSCFDictionary initWithObjects:forKeys:count:]: attempt to insert nil value at objects[0] (key: sourceRelationship)'
>   *** Call stack at first throw: (  0   CoreFoundation                      0x018655a9 **exceptionPreprocess + 185  1   libobjc.A.dylib
>
>   0x01a66313 objc_exception_throw + 44  2   CoreFoundation
>
>   0x017aedcb -[__NSPlaceholderDictionary initWithObjects:forKeys:count:]
>   + 587     3   CoreFoundation                      0x017c76da +[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:forKey:] + 74    4   CoreData                            0x0135bdea -[_NSSQLTableMigrationDescription
>   appendStatementsToPrepareForMigration:migrationContext:] + 1178   5
>
>   CoreData                            0x01357254
>   -[_NSSQLiteStoreMigrator createEntityMigrationStatements] + 356   6   CoreData                            0x01356246
>   -[_NSSQLiteStoreMigrator performMigration:] + 86  7   CoreData                            0x0135c78f -[NSSQLiteInPlaceMigrationManager
>   migrateStoreFromURL:type:options:withMappingModel:toDestinationURL:destinationType:destinationOptions:error:]
>   + 1039    8   CoreData                            0x013414ca -[NSStoreMigrationPolicy(InternalMethods) migrateStoreAtURL:toURL:storeType:options:withManager:error:] + 154    9
>   CoreData                            0x01342052
>   -[NSStoreMigrationPolicy migrateStoreAtURL:withManager:metadata:options:error:] + 146     10 
>   CoreData                            0x01342f83
>   -[NSStoreMigrationPolicy(InternalMethods) _gatherDataAndPerformMigration:] + 1315     11  CoreData                            0x01256aec -[NSPersistentStoreCoordinator
>   addPersistentStoreWithType:configuration:URL:options:error:] + 2412
>     12  AppName                            0x0007aae7
>   -[AppDelegate persistentStoreCoordinator] + 791   13  AppName                            0x0007a621
>   -[AppDelegate managedObjectContext] + 97  14  AppName                            0x0007c3cd -[AppDelegate getSettings] + 125  15  AppName
>
>   0x00078160 -[BagAppDelegate refreshSettings] + 48     16 
>   AppName                            0x00077cd7
>   -[AppDelegate application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:] + 391   17  UIKit                               0x00409c89
>   -[UIApplication _callInitializationDelegatesForURL:payload:suspended:] + 1163     18  UIKit                               0x0040bd88 -[UIApplication _runWithURL:payload:launchOrientation:statusBarStyle:statusBarHidden:] + 439     19  UIKit                               0x00416617 -[UIApplication handleEvent:withNewEvent:] + 1533    20  UIKit                               0x0040eabf -[UIApplication sendEvent:] + 71     21  UIKit
>
>   0x00413f2e _UIApplicationHandleEvent + 7576   22  GraphicsServices
>
>   0x01f03992 PurpleEventCallback + 1550     23  CoreFoundation
>
>   0x01846944 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE1_PERFORM_FUNCTION**
>   + 52  24  CoreFoundation                      0x017a6cf7 __CFRunLoopDoSource1 + 215   25  CoreFoundation                      0x017a3f83 __CFRunLoopRun + 979     26  CoreFoundation
>   0x017a3840 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 208     27  CoreFoundation
>   0x017a3761 CFRunLoopRunInMode + 97    28  UIKit
>   0x0040b7d2 -[UIApplication _run] + 623    29  UIKit
>   0x00417c93 UIApplicationMain + 1160   30  AppName
>   0x0000232d main + 125     31  AppName
>   0x000022a5 start + 53

and it shows the error as being here, when I set the persistentStoreCoordinator:

```
NSError *error;
if (![persistentStoreCoordinator addPersistentStoreWithType:NSSQLiteStoreType configuration:nil URL:storeUrl options:options error:&error]) {
    // Update to handle the error appropriately.
    NSLog(@"App Delegate - persistentStoreCoordinator Save Error %@, %@", error, [error userInfo]);
    exit(-1);  // Fail
}  
return persistentStoreCoordinator;
```

I'm pretty sure that latter code is okay - I have never had any problem with it.

The error clearly has something to do with lightweight migration and for the life of me I can't figure out what. I have been sitting here in tears for hours  (but I'm a girl so that's okay .. jk) and nothing seems to work, and I haven't gotten any good info from google searches.

I am not updating an existing app just trying to install a new one when this happens.

I really need help desperately, usually I have some idea of what to do but I am so lost in space right now. Thanks in advance for any insights.

EDIT: Thought it might have something to do with repairing disk permissions. Didn't work. Seems like there is something wrong with a mapping model. I guess it would be the automatically created one(s) because I didn't create any.

Comment: I'm pretty sure you verified this anyway, but are the values of `storeURL` and `options` correct at the time of the invocation? And what makes you think the error is related to lightweight migration?

Comment: @edsko, Yes, this exact code has worked for months on many different devices and even operating systems (4.3 prior to 5.0 upgrade). I will post the rest of the error message above to show why I think it has to do with lightweight migration, I probably should have in the beginning.

Comment: I see. When you get the crash, should a migration actually happen? (i.e., is the database in a pre-current-model state)? Do you get the crash when you start with empty database?

Comment: Yes, I get the crash when I start with an empty database. The database is not in a preCurrentModel State. The migration should not actually happen.

Comment: How many models do you have? Could you delete some to try and track down which one is causing the problem?

Also, just on the off-chance that this is related: I have had very weird problems with XCode 4.2 (parts of my models missing entirely at runtime), which was fixed by following the hint at http://twoshotsofcocoa.com/?p=51.

Comment: @edsko, THANK YOU. Your second comment actually got me thinking hard and I realized that a while back when I added another data model I never went back in and recreated the default database. I had only changed some int values from 16- to 32-, and it continued to work while I was on iOS 5, but freaked out on iOS 4.3. In any case, you absolutely saved me, and I can't tell you how appreciative I am. I just really helped that you took the time to answer when you did. Can you post your comments as an answer, & I will accept? Also, is there a way I can give you some reputation points to say thanks?

Comment: Posted the comments an an answer, though obviously I didn't really solve the problem for you :) Glad I could help though! I know how frustrating it can be sometimes..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not really an answer, but a few things you could think about to try and track down the problem:

- Are the values of `storeURL` and `options` correct at the time of the invocation?
- When you get the crash, should a migration actually happen? (i.e., is the database in a pre-current-model state)? Do you get the crash when you start with empty database?
- How many models do you have? Could you delete some to try and track down which one is causing the problem?

Comment: Thanks again. This is not for the faint of heart :)